# How to know when the server has received the whole request?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am implementing the HTTP/1.1 protocol from scratch for academic purpose. I have implemented the `RequestBuilder` which builds the request object successively from the buffer passed. This is the code to handle the opened socket.

```rust
async fn process_socket(stream: TcpStream) -> Result<Request> {
    let mut request_builder = RequestBuilder::new();
    let mut buffer: [u8; 1024] = unsafe { MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init() };

    loop {
        stream.readable().await?;
        match stream.try_read(&mut buffer) {
            Ok(0) => {
                break;
            }
            Ok(n) => (),
            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
                continue;
            }
            Err(e) => {
                return Err(e.into());
            }
        }
        request_builder.parse(&buffer);
    }

    let request = request_builder.build()?;
    Ok(request)
}
```

`request_builder.parse(&buffer);` will take the next part of the buffer and parses the request further. My question is, how to break the loop when the client has sent the whole request. When I make a request to the server using `curl localhost:8080`, the whole request is parsed.

#### Expected behaviour

The loop would have been broken after reading the whole request stream.

#### Actual behaviour

The loop is stuck at `stream.readable().await?;` after reading the whole request into buffer. Currently, when I kill `curl` command using `Ctrl+C`, the loop is broken using `Ok(0)`, but I want it to break after reading the who

Comment: I am not very familiar with http, but as a random guess, I guess you need to check if the data receive is over ? if I recall no body would mean a empty final line at the end.

Comment: No, there will always be double CRLF (`\r\n\r\n`) after the headers. It may or may not have body after that. The problem is, actually, independent of HTTP. I want to break the loop as soon as client has done sending the data and server has received all in the stream.

Comment: "No, there will always be double CRLF (\r\n\r\n) after the headers. It may or may not have body after that" so exactly as I said "if no body it's end with a empty new line"

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of how socket work ? That not something you can easily handle like `if client.have_finish_send_the_data()`

Comment: No, the empty line doesn't tell that there is no body. It seprates the headers and body. No I don't have much knowledge about the sockets. Please guide me how to handle the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interpret the HTTP request, as the TCP connection will not get half-closed by a client. A `FIN` by the client which would violate the protocol) is the only way `readable()` returns (with an `Err`) unless the client sends more data (which breaks the HTTP specification).

Comment: I see, we need to make use of Content-length, Transfer-encoding header etc to break the loop. Thank you for the answer. I will look more into it.